# node multiple view folders

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make node (or express? I'm still a noob so I don't know which is doing the actual work here) render views from multiple folders. So if I have a log in page, then there is a separate folder with index.ejs for log in, and other files for log in. and for my main page, a different folder with index etc...

I found this link which was helpful https://strongloop.com/strongblog/bypassing-express-view-rendering-for-speed-and-modularity/ however they give examples for the jade rendering engine and marko. I'm using `ejs` and I'm trying the examples they have but they're not working. For example:

I tried this one:

```
var templatePath = require.resolve('./template.jade');
var templateFn = require('jade').compileFile(templatePath);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.write(templateFn({name: 'Frank'});
    res.end();
});
```

but I replaced `require('jade')` with `require('ejs')` but then I get an error on `compileFile(templatePath)`:

> undefined is not a function

I also tried the other example with marko

```
var templatePath = require.resolve('./template.marko');
var template = require('marko').load(templatePath);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    template.render({name: 'Frank'}, res);
});
```

but got the same error on `load(templatePath)`. I can't figure out how to make node render views from locations other than the root `views` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ejs` only has a `compile()` function that takes in a string version of the template as an argument. So you will need to load the template from disk manually first:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var templatePath = require.resolve('./template.ejs');
var template = require('ejs').compile(fs.readFileSync(templatePath, 'utf8'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.end(template({name: 'Frank'}));
});
```

Comment: one question about this. What's `fs`

Comment: `fs` is one of the core modules described in the [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/).